# How to Fix Y-Axis Scrollbar Getting Doubled in a Bootstrap Scrollable Content Layout with Fixed Footer?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I got navigation menu from
https://codepen.io/Serhii75/pen/OEQrgM

I need to make footer always visible and to add scrolling if content of the page is too big.
In `CSS`, I modified:

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px !important;
    /* set fixed height of the footer */
    background-color: #ccc;
}


.content-wrapper {
    margin-left: 230px;
    height: calc(100vh - (35px + 12px) );
    /* calculated height without footer and padding */
    overflow: auto;
}
```

It works, but I see the y-axis scrollbars got doubled. See https://prnt.sc/u20wjb

My full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sidebar Nav</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto sidenav" id="navAccordion">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse" href="#" id="hasSubItems" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseSubItems2" aria-controls="collapseSubItems2" aria-expanded="false">Item 2</a>
            <ul class="nav-second-level collapse" id="collapseSubItems2" data-parent="#navAccordion">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <span class="nav-link-text">Item 2.1</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <span class="nav-link-text">Item 2.2</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse" href="#" id="hasSubItems" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseSubItems4" aria-controls="collapseSubItems4" aria-expanded="false">Item 4</a>
            <ul class="nav-second-level collapse" id="collapseSubItems4" data-parent="#navAccordion">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <span class="nav-link-text">Item 4.1</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <span class="nav-link-text">Item 4.2</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <span class="nav-link-text">Item 4.2</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline ml-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Main Content</h1>


        Content
        <br /><br /> Emulates height 100% with a horizontal flexbox with stretch
        <br /><br /> This box with a border should fill the blue area except for the padding (just to show the middle flexbox item).

        <p>Lorem <strong>ipsum dolor sit</strong> amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis <strong>nostrud exercitation</strong> ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
          ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        ...
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      </div>
    </main>

    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
          <span>Coded by <a href="https://si-dev.com/ru">SI-Dev</a>, 2018</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>

  <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


  <script src="/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <style>
    html {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      padding-top: 4.5rem;
      margin-bottom: 4.5rem;
    }
    
    .footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 35px !important;
      /*height: 3.5rem;*/
      /*line-height: 3.5rem;*/
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    
    .nav-link:hover {
      transition: all 0.4s;
    }
    
    .nav-link-collapse:after {
      float: right;
      content: '\f067';
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    }
    
    .nav-link-show:after {
      float: right;
      content: '\f068';
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    }
    
    .nav-item ul.nav-second-level {
      padding-left: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-item ul.nav-second-level>.nav-item {
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .sidenav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 230px;
        height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);
        margin-top: 3.5rem;
        background: #343a40;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }
      .navbar-expand-lg .sidenav {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .content-wrapper {
        margin-left: 230px;
        height: calc(100vh - (35px + 12px));
        /* Set max height */
        overflow: auto;
      }
      .footer {
        width: calc(100% - 230px);
        margin-left: 230px;
        height: 35px !important;
      }
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.nav-link-collapse').on('click', function() {
        $('.nav-link-collapse').not(this).removeClass('nav-link-show');
        $(this).toggleClass('nav-link-show');
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

How to fix doubled y-axis scrollbars? I am only after 1 scrollbar and that is for the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have some margin at the `body` element which causes the extra space between the footer and the content. I suggest removing that, after that just make some height adjustments to your content and the body scrollbar should go away.

Finally, I also recommend to add some padding at the bottom of the content to cater the absolute positioned footer.

```
body {
    padding-top: 4.5rem;
    /* margin-bottom: 4.5rem; */
    /* remove the margin */
}

.content-wrapper {
    margin-left: 230px;

    /* subtrahend in this equation should be based off of header & footer box model height summation */
    height: calc(100vh - (35px + 45px));

    overflow: auto;

    /* add some padding to cater the absolute footer */
    padding-bottom: 35px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sidebar Nav</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto sidenav" id="navAccordion">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse" href="#" id="hasSubItems" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseSubItems2" aria-controls="collapseSubItems2" aria-expanded="false">Item 2</a>
            <ul class="nav-second-level collapse" id="collapseSubItems2" data-parent="#navAccordion">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <span class="nav-link-text">Item 2.1</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <span class="nav-link-text">Item 2.2</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse" href="#" id="hasSubItems" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseSubItems4" aria-controls="collapseSubItems4" aria-expanded="false">Item 4</a>
            <ul class="nav-second-level collapse" id="collapseSubItems4" data-parent="#navAccordion">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <span class="nav-link-text">Item 4.1</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <span class="nav-link-text">Item 4.2</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <span class="nav-link-text">Item 4.2</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline ml-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Main Content</h1>


        Content
        <br /><br /> Emulates height 100% with a horizontal flexbox with stretch
        <br /><br /> This box with a border should fill the blue area except for the padding (just to show the middle flexbox item).

        <p>Lorem <strong>ipsum dolor sit</strong> amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis <strong>nostrud exercitation</strong> ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
          ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        ...
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      </div>
    </main>

    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
          <span>Coded by <a href="https://si-dev.com/ru">SI-Dev</a>, 2018</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>

  <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


  <script src="/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <style>
    html {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      padding-top: 4.5rem;
      /*margin-bottom: 4.5rem;*/
    }
    
    .footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 35px !important;
      /*height: 3.5rem;*/
      /*line-height: 3.5rem;*/
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    
    .nav-link:hover {
      transition: all 0.4s;
    }
    
    .nav-link-collapse:after {
      float: right;
      content: '\f067';
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    }
    
    .nav-link-show:after {
      float: right;
      content: '\f068';
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    }
    
    .nav-item ul.nav-second-level {
      padding-left: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-item ul.nav-second-level>.nav-item {
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .sidenav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 230px;
        height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);
        margin-top: 3.5rem;
        background: #343a40;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }
      .navbar-expand-lg .sidenav {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .content-wrapper {
        margin-left: 230px;
        height: calc(100vh - (35px + 37px));
        /* Set max height */
        overflow: auto;
        padding-bottom: 35px;
      }
      .footer {
        width: calc(100% - 230px);
        margin-left: 230px;
        height: 35px !important;
      }
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.nav-link-collapse').on('click', function() {
        $('.nav-link-collapse').not(this).removeClass('nav-link-show');
        $(this).toggleClass('nav-link-show');
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it works on small devices, but not work on big devices, where I have doubled horizontal scrolling again.

Comment: It works on my 1080p 24.5 inch monitor. Try adjusting the height. Did you also get rid of the margin?

Comment: Yes, I left margin-left only for  definitions of content-wrapper and footer classes

Comment: How about the `body`? It is essential you get rid of that bottom margin as well. Look at my snippet in full screen - it is working on large screens. Can you link here an updated CodePen so I can examine your changes?

Comment: I tried to get rid of margin of body and also I tried to set margin: 0 !important; and both did not help.  Also you code seems not valid :  https://prnt.sc/u25ryn

Comment: adjust the `height` a little bit more on `.content-wrapper`. example: `height: calc(100vh - (35px + 50px));`. arbitrary value to fulfill requirements - should be based off of header & footer box model height summation